# Refresh SearchView, when changing RecyclerView item

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am struggling with a problem - trying to refresh search results after the RecyclerView item is removed.

Right now, when I have filtered items out and delete one of them, RecyclerView shows all other items again, without a search filter applied.
But how to implement search filter so, that it stays on even when RecyclerView list has changed?

This is how I load data in main activity:

```
private void loadData(final int ordernumber) {

    orderLineViewModel.getAllUnCheckedSingleOrderLines(ordernumber).observe(this, new Observer<List<OrderLine>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<OrderLine> orderLines) {

            orderLineListAdapter.setOrderLines(orderLines);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my SearchView code in main activity:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            orderLineListAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            orderLineListAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is my filter in RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public void setOrderLines(List<OrderLine> orderLines) {

    orderLineList = orderLines;
    orderLineListFull = new ArrayList<>(orderLines);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return orderFilter;
}

private Filter orderFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        List<OrderLine> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0){
            filteredList.addAll(orderLineListFull);
        }else {
            String filterPattern = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (OrderLine orderLine: orderLineListFull){
                if (orderLine.getProductCode().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    filteredList.add(orderLine);
                }
            }
        }

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        orderLineList.clear();
        orderLineList.addAll((List)filterResults.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Pressing checkbox in RecyclerView item:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        OrderLine line = orderLineList.get(position);

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.foam_in_checkbox:

                if (okCheckBox.isChecked()) {

                    line.setIsArrived(1);
                    orderLineViewModel.update(line);
                    orderLineList.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);

                } else {
                    line.setIsArrived(0);
                    orderLineViewModel.update(line);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Edit: Added whole RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class OrderLineListAdapter extends 

RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderLineListAdapter.OrderLineViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private Context context;
private final LayoutInflater orderLineInflater;
private List<OrderLine> orderLineList;
private List<OrderLine> orderLineListFull;
private OrderLineViewModel orderLineViewModel;

public OrderLineListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    orderLineInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    orderLineViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of((FoamInActivity) context).get(OrderLineViewModel.class);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public OrderLineViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = orderLineInflater.inflate(R.layout.foam_in_single_line, parent, false);

    return new OrderLineViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderLineViewHolder orderLineViewHolder, int position) {

    if (orderLineList != null) {

        OrderLine current = orderLineList.get(position);

        orderLineViewHolder.productCodeTextView.setText(current.getProductCode());
        orderLineViewHolder.orderedQuantityTextView.setText(String.valueOf(current.getOrderedQuantity()));

        orderLineViewHolder.okCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        orderLineViewHolder.okCheckBox.setChecked(false);

    } else {
        orderLineViewHolder.productCodeTextView.setText(R.string.no_open_positions);
    }
}

public void setOrderLines(List<OrderLine> orderLines) {

    orderLineList = orderLines;
    orderLineListFull = new ArrayList<>(orderLines);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    if (orderLineList != null) {
        return orderLineList.size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class OrderLineViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView productCodeTextView, orderedQuantityTextView;
    public CheckBox okCheckBox;

    public OrderLineViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        productCodeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foam_in_product_code);
        orderedQuantityTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foam_in_quantity);
        okCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foam_in_checkbox);

        okCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
        productCodeTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int position = getAdapterPosition();

        OrderLine line = orderLineList.get(position);

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.foam_in_checkbox:

                if (okCheckBox.isChecked()) {

                    line.setIsArrived(1);
                    orderLineViewModel.update(line);
                    orderLineList.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);

                } else {
                    line.setIsArrived(0);
                    orderLineViewModel.update(line);
                }

                break;

            case R.id.foam_in_product_code:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Status: " + line.getIsArrived(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return orderFilter;
}

private Filter orderFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        List<OrderLine> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0){
            filteredList.addAll(orderLineListFull);
        }else {
            String filterPattern = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (OrderLine orderLine: orderLineListFull){
                if (orderLine.getProductCode().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    filteredList.add(orderLine);
                }
            }
        }

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        orderLineList.clear();
        orderLineList.addAll((List)filterResults.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Comment: please post full code of RecyclreviewAdapter

Comment: Hello!  Added whole RecyclerViewAdapter!

Comment: Once the adapter list is filtered. Delete item from that filtered list and just notify an adapter. It will keep your filter intact. You will also need to remove that item from original list.

Answer (score 0):

Whole RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class OrderLineListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderLineListAdapter.OrderLineViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private Context context;
private final LayoutInflater orderLineInflater;
private List<OrderLine> orderLineList;
private List<OrderLine> orderLineListFull;
private OrderLineViewModel orderLineViewModel;

public OrderLineListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    orderLineInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    orderLineViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of((FoamInActivity) context).get(OrderLineViewModel.class);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public OrderLineViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = orderLineInflater.inflate(R.layout.foam_in_single_line, parent, false);

    return new OrderLineViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderLineViewHolder orderLineViewHolder, int position) {

    if (orderLineList != null) {

        OrderLine current = orderLineList.get(position);

        orderLineViewHolder.productCodeTextView.setText(current.getProductCode());
        orderLineViewHolder.orderedQuantityTextView.setText(String.valueOf(current.getOrderedQuantity()));

        orderLineViewHolder.okCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        orderLineViewHolder.okCheckBox.setChecked(false);

    } else {
        orderLineViewHolder.productCodeTextView.setText(R.string.no_open_positions);
    }
}

public void setOrderLines(List<OrderLine> orderLines) {

    orderLineList = orderLines;
    orderLineListFull = new ArrayList<>(orderLines);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    if (orderLineList != null) {
        return orderLineList.size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class OrderLineViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView productCodeTextView, orderedQuantityTextView;
    public CheckBox okCheckBox;

    public OrderLineViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        productCodeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foam_in_product_code);
        orderedQuantityTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foam_in_quantity);
        okCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foam_in_checkbox);

        okCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
        productCodeTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int position = getAdapterPosition();

        OrderLine line = orderLineList.get(position);

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.foam_in_checkbox:

                if (okCheckBox.isChecked()) {

                    line.setIsArrived(1);
                    orderLineViewModel.update(line);
                    orderLineList.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);

                } else {
                    line.setIsArrived(0);
                    orderLineViewModel.update(line);
                }

                break;

            case R.id.foam_in_product_code:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Status: " + line.getIsArrived(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return orderFilter;
}

private Filter orderFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        List<OrderLine> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0){
            filteredList.addAll(orderLineListFull);
        }else {
            String filterPattern = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (OrderLine orderLine: orderLineListFull){
                if (orderLine.getProductCode().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    filteredList.add(orderLine);
                }
            }
        }

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        orderLineList.clear();
        orderLineList.addAll((List)filterResults.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Hello! I replied to androidbash request, I added my whole RecyclerViewAdapter.

Comment: Please don't update question as an answer, you can edit your question instead

Comment: thank you I didn't notice that you are the one who asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Attaching a Sample : Please update your Adapter as

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewHolder> implements
        Filterable {

    private List<Status> statusList;
    private List<Status> statusListFiltered;
    private OnClickActionListener listener;

    public ListAdapter(List<Status> statusList,
            OnClickActionListener listener) {
        this.statusList = statusList;
        this.statusListFiltered = statusList;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Status status = statusListFiltered.get(position);
        holder.cellListBinding.setStatus(status);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (statusListFiltered != null) {
            return statusListFiltered.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        CellListBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
                .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.cell_list,
                        parent, false);
        return new ListViewHolder(binding);
    }

    /**
     * Reloads list of rooms.
     */
    public void loadRooms(List<Status> roomsList) {
        this.statusList = roomsList;
        this.statusListFiltered = roomsList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    statusListFiltered = statusList;
                } else {
                    List<Status> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Status row : statusList) {
                        if (row.getStatusName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    statusListFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = statusListFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                if (filterResults.values instanceof RealmList) {
                    statusListFiltered = (RealmList<Status>) filterResults.values;
                } else {
                    statusListFiltered = (ArrayList<Status>) filterResults.values;
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {

        // Your Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! I made all changes, except checking if filterResults.values are instanceof RealmList (I could not implement it). 
But still filtering goes away, as soon as I remove one of the RecyclerView item.

Comment: Yeah so filter text needs to be stored in activity/adapter and you need to call getFilter with the stored text